# Conditionally remove numbers and calculate summary statistics

Tags: r

I have a data.frame that looks like this:

```
 Col1       Col2     Col3     Mean    
   5         6        5        5.3     
   3         7        9        6.3    
   1         3        4        2.6
```

I would like to remove row-wise the number that differs more from the mean of each row and re-calculate the mean with the remaining two numbers.

Can anyone help me please?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please add your expected output as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Data**

```
df = read.csv(text = "Col1,Col2,Col3,Mean
                      5,6,5,5.3
                      3,7,9,6.3
                      1,3,4,2.6", header = TRUE)
```

Remove the values for each row furthest from row mean and create a new dataframe

```
df2 = t(apply(df[,1:3], 1, function(x) x[-which.max(abs(x-mean(x)))]))
```

Calculate `rowMeans` for the rows in `df2`

```
df2 = cbind(df2,Mean = rowMeans(df2))
```

Answer (score 4):

Could be done with `dplyr/tidyr` like so:
Generate dataframe in question:

```
df<-data.frame(Col1=sample(1:10,3),Col2=sample(1:10,3),Col3=sample(1:10,3))%>%mutate(Mean=rowMeans(.))
```

For example:

```
>df
  Col1 Col2 Col3     Mean
1    6   10    3 6.333333
2    7    6    1 4.666667
3    9    4    4 5.666667
```

Then `gather` the columns , use the condition to `filter`, `spread` the resulting tbl_df to the original form, `select` everything but the Mean column  and recalculate `rowMeans`:

```
df_fin<-df%>%gather(Cols,value,Col1:Col3)%>%filter(value>Mean)%>%spread(Cols, value)%>%select(-Mean)%>%mutate(newMean=rowMeans(.,na.rm=TRUE))
```

This will give you:

```
    > df_fin
  Col1 Col2 newMean
1    7    6     6.5
2    9   NA     9.0
3   NA   10    10.0
```

Answer (score 3):

We can set the elements in the first 3 columns that are greater than the 'Mean' column to 'NA', then recalculate the row means (`rowMeans`) based on the new values and assign it to 'Mean' column

```
df1[1:3][df1[1:3] > df1$Mean] <- NA
df1$Mean <- rowMeans(df1[1:3], na.rm = TRUE)
```

---

Or in a single line

```
df1$Mean <- rowMeans(replace(df1[1:3], df1[1:3] > df1$Mean, NA), na.rm = TRUE)
```

---

Or as @Alexey Ferapontov mentioned, the logic could be different

```
df1[cbind(1:nrow(df1), max.col(df1[1:3]- df1$Mean, "first"))] <- NA
rowMeans(df1[1:3], na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: I think the author needed to remove element that has largest difference with the mean. E.g. in row 3 it would be "1" (1.6 diff), not "4" (1.4 diff)